# Google API translation return error

Tags: java, google-api

i have a part of code that use google api translate , i write my code like this

```
package pp;

import com.google.api.GoogleAPI;
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;


public class tr
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");
         GoogleAPI.setKey("AIzaSyBi7y4EgC0B-Q9UZg-tOzsOI0sLQ8F1Oow");

        String result = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("hello", Language.ENGLISH, Language.ARABIC);

        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("succeeded");


    }


    }
```

but when i run it i get this error

debug result :
    Error: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.

run result

```
Error: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.GoogleAPIException: java.lang.Exception: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
    at com.google.api.translate.TranslateV2.execute(TranslateV2.java:68)
    at pp.tr.main(tr.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
    at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:99)
    at com.google.api.translate.TranslateV2.execute(TranslateV2.java:62)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyBi7y4EgC0B-Q9UZg-tOzsOI0sLQ8F1Oow&q=hello&target=ar&source=en
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1458)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1452)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1106)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:93)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyBi7y4EgC0B-Q9UZg-tOzsOI0sLQ8F1Oow&q=hello&target=ar&source=en
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1403)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:89)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: The HTTP response code 403 means "Forbidden". Are you sure you're using the correct URL for the Google translation service, and are you sure you're authorised to use the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable the Translate API from the Services tab of your project in the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

This page contains all pricing details: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing