# GoogleAPI HttpReferrer Error

Tags: java, google-translate

I am using Google Translate API eample from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/) so far i have:-

- Downloaded and added google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar to my classpath
- Created a project in the console.developers.google.com and activated the Tranlate API as 
  well as generated the API Key
- My Dev environemnt = Eclipse 3.4, Java 1.7, Apache Tomcat 7.0.55, RichFaces 3.3

My code snippet is as follows:-

```
import com.google.api.GoogleAPIException;
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;
import com.google.api.GoogleAPI;

public class TranslateCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) {

GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");
GoogleAPI.setKey("my api key here");

String translatedText="";
try {
  translatedText = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("Anger", Language.ENGLISH,Language.URDU);
   } catch (GoogleAPIException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
System.out.println(translatedText);

 }
 }
```

And the error i get is:-

```
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:   
 https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?
 key=AIsdfabCSW_HEREplZ7vfUwaC34YmVT_F1m9Ps&q=Anger&target=ur&source=en
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:89)
    ... 2 more
```

I know this is seem like a duplicate of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121227/google-api-translation-return-error). But my question here is that, how do it know exactly the CORRECT url for the setHTTPheader. i tried using following

```
 https://console.developers.google.com/
```

But to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the API key in the developer console.So there are several options to create a key (Browser Key, Server Key, IOS Key etc). Suppose, you select the Key called Server key, then you have to provide the IP address of the machine, which you want to allow to consume your APIs, if you didn't provide any IP then all public Ip address can consume it. Similar is for Browser and IOS Key. Go through the document [1] to understand the capping usage.

[1] https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#cappingusage